# Logback Custom Data Base appender for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I am creating a java spring boot application and I have a requirement to log (info logs) into specific database table. For this I have created a custom appender class extending AppenderBase class. now the issue is that in my custom appender class I want to create/access a jdbctemplate object using database properties provided in the spring's application.properties file.

How can i access spring's jdbctemplate object in my custom appender?

Here is the code sample -

```
public class MyDBAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
     protected void append(ILoggingEvent eventObject) {
       jdbcTemplate.savelog(....);
   } 
}
```

Comment: How does your appender look like?

Comment: Added code sample. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a Spring Bean of your MyDBAppender by adding the `@Component` annotation on the class level.

Or if you don't want to do that or if this does not work you can create a helper class to access the ApplicationContext:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanType) {
        return context.getBean(beanType);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
        context = ac;
    }

}
```

To access the JdbcTemplate use is it like this.

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = ApplicationContextProvider.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
```